Mantener valores <select> al recargar
Tengo un pequeño buscador en HTML y PHP. Mi problema es que una vez realizo la búsqueda y se cargan los resultados no se mantienen los valores de los <select> y me gustaría, si es posible, que se mantuviesen. ¿Alguna ayuda?
<form name="formulario" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <select name="año">
            <option value="2024">2024</option>
            <option value="2023">2023</option>
        </select>

        <select name="tipo">
            <option value="1">Vacaciones</option>
            <option value="2">Enfermedad</option>
            <option value="3">Baja</option>
        </select>        
        <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR">
    </form>


Un <select> marca el primer <option>, a menos que existe alguno con el atributo selected presente, en cuyo casó esa será la opción seleccionada


<select>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2" selected>2</option>
<select>



Notar que no importa el valor que tenga selected, solo importa que esté presente:


<select>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 
 <!-- Aun que sea falso, queda seleccionado -->
 <option value="2" selected="false">2</option>
<select>



En PHP solo tienes que evaluar si el dato que te llega es el que corresponde a cada <option>, para esto existen mil formas de hacerlo, aquí te dejo un ejemplo que utiliza una función para generarlo
    <?php
       function CreateOption($name,$value,$text=null){
          $text = $text == null ? $value : $text;
          if($_POST[$name] == $value){  //El valor del POST es el mismo del option??? si así este option estará seleccionado
              echo "<option value='{$value}' selected>{$text}</option>";
          }
          else{
              echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$text}</option>";
          }
      }
    ?>


   <form name="formulario" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <select name="year">
            <?php
             CreateOption("year",2024);
             CreateOption("year",2023);
            ?>
        </select>

        <select name="tipo" >
            <?php 
             CreateOption("tipo",1,"Vacaciones");
             CreateOption("tipo",2,"Enfermedad");
             CreateOption("tipo",3,"Baja");
            ?>
        </select>        
        <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR">
    </form>


